# How to use HTML inside of translatable strings in Qt?

Tags: qt, translation

The Qt [tutorial](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/i18n-source-translation.html) for translatable texts does not mention whether it is possible to use HTML inside of a translatable string.

However, [some examples](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-1136) I found use it, so it seems to be possible.

However, if I so much as use `"<B>text</B>"` in my .ts file, Qt Linguist does not open it. It displays the error message "unexpected tag" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ts file is XML.  If you want to use HTML tags you will need to escape them.  For example: `<source>&lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;</source>`

Note that the recommended way of managing translations in Qt is to run the lupdate tool on your source code and have Qt generate the .ts file, in which case this will be done automatically.